# Why variable of data type "id" can't be a pointer, in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective-C and i am curious to know more about `id` data type. I am wondering why the variable of data type `id` can't be a pointer.

While declaring a variable I learnt that we should make it a pointer, e.g.

```
SomeClass *someVar = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

but in case of `id` type, its simply like:

```
id someVar = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
```

Here, `id` type is no longer a pointer. Why?

Comment: Thanks DarkDust, url suggestion, that helps

Comment: Its my first question here, and i am feeling so good that i got my question answered within few minutes. Thank you all!

Comment: Who have told you that `id` can't be a pointer? Try `const id* selfPtr = &self;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is a generic pointer type to an Objective-C object where you don't know what the class is. But it is a pointer type.

Comment: Thanks Wain for quick and prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

id is a pointer to an object, like (NSObject *), but is special in that it doesn’t use an asterisk. This might help: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW18